# Oracle SQL ignores condition in WHERE clause

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this simple part of SQL query

```
where aia.invoice_num in (:invoice_num) or aia.invoice_num is null
and ipa.payment_date between (:start_date) and (:end_date) or ipa.payment_date >= (:start_date) or (:start_date is null and :end_date is null)
and ipa.PAYEE_NAME in (:payee) or :payee is null
```

I have 4 parameters, `invoice_num`, `start_date`, `end_date` and `Payee`, I want it to be just like a filter, If one of the conditions above is present then it must be applied, if not present then it must be ignored, but it just doesn't work as expected, if I pass `invoice_num` the result will be all the invoices anyway whether other parameters are present or null, how can I force every condition if present and make it ignored if `null` ?

Comment: MySQL and Oracle are two different RDBMSes, which one are you using?

Comment: Oracle DBMS for sure

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your query does not work because:

1. `AND` has a higher operator precedence than `OR` which means it is evaluated as:

   ```sql
   where ( aia.invoice_num in (:invoice_num) )
   or    (     aia.invoice_num is null
           and ipa.payment_date between (:start_date) and (:end_date) )
   or    ( ipa.payment_date >= (:start_date) )
   or    ( :start_date is null
           and :end_date is null
           and ipa.PAYEE_NAME in (:payee) )
   or    ( :payee is null )
   ```

   so if any of the `OR` conditions is true then the rest can be ignored.
2. You compare `aia.invoice_num is null` rather than `:invoice_num IS NULL`.

To fix it, you can use:

```sql
WHERE ( aia.invoice_num = :invoice_num  OR :invoice_num IS NULL )
AND   ( ipa.payment_date >= :start_date OR :start_date  IS NULL )
AND   ( ipa.payment_date <= :end_date   OR :end_date    IS NULL )
AND   ( ipa.PAYEE_NAME   = :payee       OR :payee       IS NULL )
```

Comment: ohh, so the parentheses, i have no idea why is this a thing.. but it worked

Comment: @aasemshoshari `AND` has a higher operator precedence than `OR`. If you want to evaluate them in a different order of precedence then you need brackets.